# Плавное удлинение блока и появление кнопок

Tags: html, css, css-animation, z-index

Соответственно, при наведении на карточку снизу появляются 2 кнопки, и блок вырастает по вертикали.

```css
/*У карточки есть свойства,
чтобы выводить класс info над другими карточками : */

.card-body {
  position: relative;
}

.card-body:hover .card {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}


/*На класс info применены следующие свойства : */

.info {
  display: none;
}

.card:hover .info {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!--Имеется вот такая карточка:-->

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="name">Name</div>
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <div class="info">
      <div class="details">Подробнее</div>
      <div class="buy">Купить</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как настроить плавную анимацию таким образом, чтобы и блок удлинялся постепенно и кнопки "открывались" по мере удлинения блока?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь, понятно описал. Спасибо.

Comment: `display` не анимируется

Answer (score 1):

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 38px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: blue;
  transition: height .5s;
}

.card:hover {
  height: 180px;
}

.card-body {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 180px;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="name">Name</div>
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <div class="info">
      <div class="details">Подробнее</div>
      <div class="buy">Купить</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно зато аннимировать внутреннее содержимое и выставлять эффекты на него - смотрим

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  margin: 3px 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.items {
  width: 200px;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  margin: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  padding: 4px;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
  transition: 0.64s linear 1s;
  background: inherit;
}

.items:hover .hidden {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  некое описание которое видно
  <div class="hidden">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, mollitia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Optio vero quas facere mollitia recusandae amet, quod ratione neque blanditiis sapiente tempora voluptas aliquid, ipsam libero
    minima officia fugit? Nobis, dolorum.
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <a href="">какая то кнопка</a>
    <a href="">важная кнопка</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой вариант. Для того, чтобы все сработало - нужно знать высоту в `px` вашего объекта

```css
/*У карточки есть свойства,
чтобы выводить класс info над другими карточками : */

.card-body {
  position: relative;
}

.card-body:hover .card {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}


/*На класс info применены следующие свойства : */

.info {
    margin-top: 100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:0;
    transition: height .5s ease-in;
}

.card:hover .info {
  height: 200px;
  
}
```

```html
<!--Имеется вот такая карточка:-->

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="name">Name</div>
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <div class="info">
      <div class="details">Подробнее</div>
      <div class="buy">Купить</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```